# Using the ServiceLocator in ZF2 with Doctrine 2 from/in a Custom Class?

Tags: frameworks, doctrine, zend-framework2

i have a little problem using doctrine 2 in Zend Framework 2 i have custome class that i use to manipulate doctrine generated model (basically to inject data and populate), to make that work i need the entity manager which is available through the service manager as indicated in Jason Grimes tutorial here http://www.jasongrimes.org/2012/01/using-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-2/.

In his tutorial it works (i tested it) as the ServiceLocator is called from a controller class, but for the application i am writing i have to use custom (non controller) classes to interact with the entities.  How do i achieve this? Using the servicelocator from a custom class that is not a controller?  Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two steps

- Implement `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` in your custom class. This allows to the Framework to inject the Service Locator for you.
- Convert your custom class to a service and retrieve it using Service Manager. This component will check if the class implement ServiceLocatorAwareInterface and the inject the ServiceLocator before returning to you the instance

Comment: thank you i will test that as soon as possible and will report back for everybody to be able to get it!