# How to use the Repository class in ZF2?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework2, repository-pattern

I am trying to understand the Repository class in Zend Framework in order to choose the right way to create my new software application.

What I need is clarify the concept of the Repository. I have read that I can call the ServiceLocator, get the EntityManager, now call the Repository from my Controller action and execute the Doctrine methods passing the data to the view:

[image]

Then I have read this answer in stackoverflow and now I am a little bit confused: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14103376/1034359

So what is the right way or better way to call the Entities ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use an existing module to connect to the doctrine orm library: http://modules.zendframework.com/?query=Doctrine+orm